# Specify the DependencyProperty of a UIElement in a BeginAnimation

Tags: wpf, animation, render, dependency-properties

I am trying to animate a Ellipse to move from a point A to a point B on a canvas.

```
public void AnimateSensor(double x, double y, Ellipse sensor)
    {
        if (!Double.IsNaN(x))
        {
            DoubleAnimation animX = new DoubleAnimation();
            animX.To = x;
            animX.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            DoubleAnimation animY = new DoubleAnimation();
            animY.To = y;
            animY.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            TranslateTransform rt = new TranslateTransform();
            sensor.RenderTransform = rt;

            rt.BeginAnimation(sensor.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), animX);
            rt.BeginAnimation(sensor.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), animY);
           }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("x or y is NaN");
    }
```

I call this method with a set of coordinates and a Ellipse , howerver I can't seem to figure out how to specify the dependecy value in the BeginAnimation . I tryed witn 'sensor.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)' but it says it is an object and need a dependency property. When i use 'as DependencyProperty' it made it null and when I tryed to cast it , it sayd you can't cast from double to DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would either animate the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties of the Ellipse, without a TranslateTransform, like this:

```
sensor.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animX);
sensor.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, animY);
```

or the `X` and `Y` properties of the TranslateTransform, like this:

```
if (!(sensor.RenderTransform is TranslateTransform))
{
    // assign RenderTransform only once
    sensor.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
}

var transform = (TranslateTransform)sensor.RenderTransform;
transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animX);
transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, animY);
```